# Need phonectics in Kaldi decoding

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, kaldi

I am using aspire example in KALDI. And it's working fine. Just there is one help that I need and it is that I need phonetics of an audio file while decoding.
So basically when I decode a .wav file I need phonetics of audio instead of the word(sentence).
example: 
word: ago
phonetics: ago ah_B g_I ow_E

Is it possible? if yes then please help.

Comment: And what is your current code?

Comment: See this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kaldi-help/Vkw8scRYoFA/2W5SvXCVBQAJ